# Array index out of bound in java error

Tags: java, arrays, collections, linked-list, file-handling

```
package com.testing;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;

public class CsvParser {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String csvFile = "D:/code-home/SentimentAnalysis/test_data/Sentiment Analysis Dataset.csv";
        BufferedReader br = null;
        String line = "";
        String cvsSplitBy = "\t";   // data is in format splitted by tab

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            // use comma as separator
            String[] tweet = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
            System.out.println(tweet[1]);
            System.out.println(tweet[3]);
        }
    }
}
```

The program's purpose is to parse the CSV format. I have used bufferRead method.

When I go to compile the program, it works fine. When I run the program,output is printed but there is a exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
at com.testing.CsvParser.main(CsvParser.java:34)
```

Comment: Did you read the [docs of `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html) ?

Comment: Print your array through a loop. `for (String s:tweet) System.out.println(s)` or use a for loop with index if u need specific element

Answer (score 2):

First of all: Arrays in Java are Zero-indexed, which means that the first element in an array is not selected by array[1] but by array[0]. Since your OutOufBoundsException is fired at the index 1, your array has at most one element in it (you shoulds check for the size of the array before accessing it). Because you are trying to access the index 3 (fourth element in Java) in the very next line i suspect you expect at least 3 elements in each line. Since there is at most one element you seem to either be using the wrong splitcharacter or your file is not formatted as you expect it to be.  I hope this helps you.  Kind regards

Comment: Yes there is some value in the array[3] and in array[1] the output shows value of these but at last it shows OutOfBoundException.....

Comment: @Madan: Then you maybe get the error when you are trying to parse the last line of the file, which is empty?